# "/content?title=....htm not found" error message

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to view my data in RStudio and I get the above strange message, what is that and how do I fix whatever problem there is? I can still work with the data, I just can't see it.

I haven't done anything special, it just "happened". I just keep trying View(df)... and now all of a sudden my data frame is an endless column of 1's, although the View window states, true enough, that df is "30 observations of 2 variables".

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `df`? (Check that your problem is also present with the sample data that you provide!) Which version of RStudio are you using?

Comment: Could you check if the `utils::View(df)` works?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem several times. For me it always helped to quit and restart RStudio. You might try this.

EDIT:
Normally when quitting RStudio without saving your workspace manually before, you should get a prompt asking you

> Save workspace image to $pathToYourWorkspace ?

If this is not the case maybe u have no writing permission in your selected workspace folder. Be sure about that first. If you have the permission you could try saving your workspace manually by entering

`save.image('$pathToYourWorkspace/.RData')`

Can you try accessing your previous entered commands in the console by using arrow up key? Does it work?
Do you have a file called .Rhistory in your workspace?
If not check Options if u have it activated (Tools -> Global Options -> General) and then check 'Restore .RData into workspace at startup' and 'Always save history ...'

You could also check if u have the latest Version of RStudio installed.

Comment: Sure, but then you have to start all over.

Comment: Normally everything you do is saved in your workspace and all your variables and functions and commands you entered in the console are also saved there. And you can also always save your code in a script file to be sure.

Comment: Is there a way to save the workspace so that variables etc are not lost when there a "fatal error", as I just encountered? RStudio just restarts with the variables showing, but View() returns object not found. "Save workspace as" doesn't seem to do anything.